# how to get text of checked checkbox in listview and transfer to another activity in android?

Tags: listview, android-intent, checkbox, bundle, adapter

I want to get text of checked checkbox in listview and transfer them to second activity on button click ..i need some code to do this....this is what i done so far..
check the pictures...[ListView1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HFtN.png) and [ListView2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfwKw.png)

this is activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btest"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="submit"
    />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btest"
    android:clickable="true"
    >
    </ListView>
```

```
view_items.xml                                      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >   <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cbCategory"
    android:text=" "
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:text="tvname"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cbCategory"
    />
```

```
result.xml <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/outputlist"
    ></ListView>
```

this is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter;
    Button btest;
    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btest);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        // adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,getModel());
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,getModel());
      // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, getModel());
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        final ArrayList<String> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView tvcheck = (TextView) view.getTag(R.id.name);
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.getTag(R.id.cbCategory);
                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                   cb.setChecked(false);
                }else {
                   cb.setChecked(true);
                }
             /*
                selectedStrings.add(tvcheck.getText().toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);
               // Bundle b = new Bundle();
              //  b.putString("selectedStrings", selectedStrings);
                i.putExtra("SelectedStrings", selectedStrings);
               // i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);*/

                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), tvcheck.getText().toString()+ "" +isCheckedOrNot(cb), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        btest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

                ArrayList<Model> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i =0; i< checked.size(); i++){
                    int pos = checked.keyAt(i);
                    if (checked.valueAt(i))
                        selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(pos));
                }
                String[] output = new String[selectedItems.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i< selectedItems.size(); i++){
                    output[i] = String.valueOf(selectedItems.get(i));
                }
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putStringArray("selectedItems", output);
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private String isCheckedOrNot(CheckBox checkBox){
        if(checkBox.isChecked())
            return "is checked";
        else
            return "is not checked";
    }
    private List<Model> getModel() {

        list.add(new Model("pulses"));
        list.add(new Model("tea"));
        list.add(new Model("Milk"));
        list.add(new Model("Sugar"));
        list.add(new Model("Salt"));
        list.add(new Model("Rice"));
        list.add(new Model("Bread"));
        list.add(new Model("Charger"));
        list.add(new Model("Mouse"));
        list.add(new Model("Mobile"));
        list.add(new Model("Laptop"));
        list.add(new Model("Bulb"));

        return list;
    }

}
```

this is my CustomAdapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context ,int res,List<Model> list){
        super(context, R.layout.view_item,res,list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }
    static class ViewHolder{
        protected TextView tvcheck;
        protected CheckBox cb;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvcheck = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbCategory);
            // final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;
            viewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                     int getPosition = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
                    list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.cb.setTag(list.get(position));
            convertView.setTag(R.id.name, viewHolder.tvcheck);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.cbCategory, viewHolder.cb);
        }else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }

        viewHolder.cb.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.tvcheck.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.cb.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

this is ResultActivity.class

```
    public class ResultActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String[] resultArr = b.getStringArray("selectedItems");
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.outputlist);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,resultArr );
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

this is the MOdel.class

```
    public class Model {
    private String name;
    private boolean selected;

    public Model(String name){
        this.name = name;
        selected = false;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected(){
        return selected;
    }
    public void setSelected(boolean selected){
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem getting using current code?

Comment: Describe your problem

Comment: i have checkboxes in listview but when i check some boxes and press button to transfer them to listview2 nothing is showing in listview2 i.e ResultActivity.java

Comment: i want to get text of checked boxes and transfer them to ResultActivity.java and show their in another listview

Comment: try a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628194/transfer-checked-items-in-listview-to-another-listivew-on-button-click-in-androi